# How to return a pointer that uses a custom constructor

Tags: c++

I'm getting this error:

`Expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction`

On the second line:

```
struct OpenALInterface * CreateOpenALInterface(int numLoadedSounds, int numPlayingSounds){
   return new IOS_OpenAL(int numLoadedSounds, int numPlayingSounds); //ERROR ABOVE
   //    return new IOS_OpenAL();  //this works fine, no error
 };
```

Class has this:

```
class IOS_OpenAL: public OpenALInterface{

 public:

IOS_OpenAL(int numLoadedSounds, int numPlayingSounds){
    //do stuff
   };

  //    IOS_OpenAL(){}; //works
```

What exactly is this error referring to? It looks like a syntax error.

The base class is abstract with no constructors. Is that the issue? Can a subclass override or have its own constructor not in the base class?

Comment: Why do you have those `int`s there?

Comment: I'm going to do something with them in `//do stuff` - it's a custom constructor.

Comment: No, I mean in the function call.

Comment: The function call is the static initializer that passes them onto the constructor so the returned pointer is to an object initialized with the desired parameters

Comment: i'm an idiot those ints are typos and shouldn't be there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return new IOS_OpenAL(int numLoadedSounds, int numPlayingSounds);
```

should be

```
return new IOS_OpenAL(numLoadedSounds, numPlayingSounds);
```

The error happens because the compiler sees those "int" tokens and thinks you're trying to cast something to an int, but you're not.

Comment: thanks i just saw my typo. sometimes putting things in a different context makes your eyes work again.

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean this:

```
struct OpenALInterface * CreateOpenALInterface(int numLoadedSounds, int numPlayingSounds){
   return new IOS_OpenAL(numLoadedSounds, numPlayingSounds);
};
```